# Integrating with Twitter

Tags: html, twitter

I hate to be doing this, but since [going through the proper channels](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-cards-not-appearing/28639) has led to being completely ignored for two weeks, I bring myself here instead. Hopefully you guys can prove why we're better ;)

I'm trying to integrate Twitter Cards, however despite following the instructions, and despite the [Validator](https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator) loading just fine ([screenshot of the validator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eII8y.png)), it fails to show up in actual Tweets.

The URL being Tweeted in this example is http://pfq.link/?Megayena and the relevant Meta tags on that page are:

```
<meta name="twitter:card"    content="product" />
<meta name="twitter:site"    content="@SystemSalamence" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@SystemSalamence" />
<meta name="twitter:domain"  content="pokefarm.com" />
<meta name="twitter:title"   content="Sei's Mightyena on PokéFarm Q" />
<meta name="twitter:image"   content="http://pfq.link/?Megayena=004000ccff99300300.png" />
<meta name="twitter:label1"  content="Species" />
<meta name="twitter:data1"   content="Mightyena [Mega Forme Q]" />
<meta name="twitter:label2"  content="Held item" />
<meta name="twitter:data2"   content="No item" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Sei's Mightyena is a Level 100 Mightyena [Mega Forme Q]. She is hungry, so come visit her on Solaria and give her a Berry!" />
```

Everything looks valid, and it works on the validator preview, so why are Tweets not getting their cards?

Comment: Sorry for the delay answering over on the [twittercommunity question](https://twittercommunity.com/t/twitter-cards-not-appearing/28639) - will take a look. I'm a bit baffled, initially thought it might have been due to your link shortener, but it doesn't seem to be the issue here.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the response - hopefully this can be investigated properly :)

Answer (score 1):

When visiting the URL and inspecting (view source in the browser) your tag  refers to a different URL than the one in the question.

it currently refers to:

> http://pokefarm.com/img/script/pokemon?00400ccff99300300Megayena

Trying to visit that image URL, It returned a HTML page that contains an error (PHP error).

maybe that is the problem.

Comment: That... that was it. It's supposed to be `004000` (ie. hex for dark green) but I missed a zero, offsetting the whole parser and messing it up. The worst part is, I could have just copy-pasted the Facebook META tags and it would have been fine. Well, I've fixed the typo, now we just need to see if Twitter recognises the change - one of the Twitter devs suggested that it may not be following the redirect, but we'll see. Meanwhile, thanks for helping find the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a summary card rather than a product card?

https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary

While I can't see any obvious errors in the code, it might be worth trying different cards and seeing if they work.

Answer (score -1):

The problem comes perhaps from there :

> The image must be a minimum size of 120px by 120px

See https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary

Comment: 200x200 qualifies as "minimum 120x120", so I don't think that's it.